# Teamcity - Skip build

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, webdeploy

I need to set up a project in teamcity that won't compile the solution in TC. Instead it will just take some compiled files from the VCS root (github) and deploy them into the IIS server using webdeploy.

how can I achieve this setup?

Some context info:

- I'm forced to use TC due to some internal policies.
- I'm not interested in unit testing for this project.
- I'm not really interested in adding complexity to my process, just keep copying
- I've already connected the VCS to the project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement in TeamCity to compile source code or collect artifacts, just use the "Command Line" build step to run `msdeploy` against the source files you checkout.